# Sort descending for negative numbers, and ascending for positive ones in same array

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

I had an interesting question: Given an array that contains unique integers. Write a function that sorts the array such that the negative numbers appear before the positive ones. The negative numbers are ordered in descending order, and the positive numbers in ascending order. And no helper arrays can be used - meaning that it all needs to be sorted "in-place"

Example:

```
int arr[] = {12, 56, -9, 4, -8, 46, 3, 7, -16, 78, 69};
```

would result in `-8 -9 -16 3 4 7 12 46 56 69 78`

I was able to write a simple program that first sorts everything in ascending order, in addition to keeping a tally of the quantity negative numbers.
Afterward, I swap the first and last position of negative numbers and proceed till the end of all them... and lastly, I return the array.

Is there a more elaborate/efficient way of doing this.

Here is my code currently:

```
int *negDescPosAsc(int *arr, int size)
{
    //treat negative numbers differently than positive numbers
    //sort negative numbers in descending order
    //sort positive numbers in ascending order
    //return the sorted array
    int negCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {

        //do normal sort then reverse the negatives
        for (int j = 0; j < size - 1; j++)
        {
            if (*(arr + j) > *(arr + j + 1))
            {
                if (*(arr + j) < 0)
                {
                    negCount++;
                }
                int temp = *(arr + j);
                *(arr + j) = *(arr + j + 1);
                *(arr + j + 1) = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    int i = 0;
    while (negCount > 0)
    {
        int temp = *(arr + i); //store the value of the current element
        *(arr + i) = *(arr + negCount); //replace the current element with the last element
        *(arr + negCount) = temp; //replace the last element with the current element
        negCount--; //decrement the negative count
        i++; //increment the index
    }
    

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for an answer besides for swapping out my swap function for something "more efficient"...

Comment: Use `std::partition` and then do 2 sorts using 2 different comparators? Also use a algorithm that takes `O(n * log(n))` for sorting instead of `O(n^2)`

Comment: @EricPostpischil taken care of!

Comment: A common answer is to adapt the comparison function. However, this requires testing the operands and selecting a subexpression each time a comparison is done, so O(n log n) times. An alternative is to preprocess the array, mapping each negative element `x` to `-1-x+INT_MIN`. (This swaps `-1` with `INT_MIN`, `-2` with `INT_MIN+1`, and so on.) Then sort in normal ascending order. Then postprocess with the inverse map (which is identical to the forward map). This replaces O(n log n) work with O(n) work.

Comment: Map each element with `x ^= x >> 31` either online or offline (given that `int` is `int32_t`).

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen: Even if `x` has type `int32_t` and is negative, the behavior of `x >> 31` is not defined by the C standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the default compare function to suite this problem. Then you can use `qsort`, or `std::sort` or your own sorting method. I'll demonstrate with `std::sort`:

```cpp
    std::vector<int> items = {12, 56, -9, 4, -8, 46, 3, 7, -16, 78, 69};
    auto comp = [](int A, int B) { return (A < 0 && B < 0) ? B < A : A < B; };
    std::sort(items.begin(), items.end(), comp);
    for (auto item : items) cout << item << " ";
    cout << endl;
```

The output is: `-8 -9 -16 3 4 7 12 46 56 69 78`

Here we check if both the numbers are negative. If they are, we reverse the comparison.

C equivalent:

```c
int compare(const void *_A, const void *_B)
{
    int A = *(const int *)_A, B = *(const int *)_B;
    return (A < 0 && B < 0) ? B > A : A > B;
}

int main()
{
    int count = 11;
    int items[] = {12, 56, -9, 4, -8, 46, 3, 7, -16, 78, 69};
    qsort(items, count, sizeof(int), compare);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) printf("%i ", items[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: not exactly what i was looking for but was certainly helpful...

Comment: Why is this not what you were looking for? As I said in the answer, the compare function is the key. you can use it in the sort function that you have written.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a simpler and more efficient way, is to use the `qsort()` standard library function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int compare(const void *ap, const void *bp)
{
    const int *aref = ap, *bref = bp, a = *aref, b = *bref;

    /* negative numbers go first. */
    if (a < 0 && b >= 0) return -1;
    if (a >= 0 && b < 0) return +1;

    /* then the absolute value of number wins. */
    return abs(a) - abs(b);
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {12, 56, -9, 4, -8, 46, 3, 7, -16, 78, 69};
    size_t arr_sz = sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0];

    qsort(arr, arr_sz, sizeof *arr, compare);

    char *sep ="";
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_sz; ++i) {
        printf("%s%d", sep, arr[i]);
        sep = ", ";
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

That produces:

```
$ a.out
-8, -9, -16, 3, 4, 7, 12, 46, 56, 69, 78
$ _
```